# post alamofire not firing

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I have been frustrated with this problem. my button not firing when posting with alamofire, but when I test to print the button if it working or not. it is working, what went wrong actually I don't know what is the solution anyway? here I show you my code please help me

```
@objc func handleSave() {
        print("save")
        guard let fullName = infos?.fullName else { return }
        guard let email = infos?.email else { return }
        guard let phoneNumber = infos?.phoneNumber else { return }
        guard let city = infos?.pobId else { return }
        guard let birth = infos?.dob else { return }
        guard let religion = infos?.religionId else { return }
        guard let imageName = userDefaults.string(forKey: "profileImage") else { return }
        guard let src = userDefaults.string(forKey: "src") else { return }

        let parameter: [String: Any] = [
            "full_name": fullName,
            "email": email,
            "pob_id": city,
            "dob": birth,
            "phone_number": phoneNumber,
            "religion_id": religion,
            "asset": [
                "id": UUID().uuidString,
                "filename": imageName,
                "content_type": "image/png",
                "src": src
            ]
        ]
        progressHUD.show(in: self.view)
        BasicInfoServices.shared.postBasicInfo(parameters: parameter) { (success) in
            if success {
                self.progressHUD.dismiss(animated: true)
                self.presentGAlertOnMainThread(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "ic-message-success"), title: "Success".localized(), message: "Success save profile".localized(), completion: nil)
            } else {
                self.progressHUD.dismiss(animated: true)
                self.presentGAlertOnMainThread(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "ic-message-failure"), title: "Failed".localized(), message: "Failed to save profile".localized(), completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }

// This is my network services
func postBasicInfo(parameters: [String: Any], completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {

        AF.request(API_URL.BASIC_INFO.USER, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: HEADERS, interceptor: nil).responseData(completionHandler: { responseData in

            debugPrint(responseData)
            if responseData.error == nil {
                completion(true)
            } else {
                completion(false)
                print("Error post info")
                return
            }

            guard let response = responseData.response, response.statusCode == 200 else {
                completion(false)
                print("Failed response")
                return
            }

            guard let data = responseData.data else {
                completion(false)
                print("Failed to fetch data")
                return
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: and with this code, you can see "save" in the log or not?

Comment: yes it print in the log. @m1sh0

Comment: the reason is success code doesn't work. Add a print code success and else part check which part is working

Comment: then the problem should be in the data that you check in all guard let constructions add one print after them or just debug

Comment: oke I'll try @m1sh0

Comment: I'll try @gihanshox

Comment: it all working, and when I try to pick date or city or anything, I print there is a value. but the service still not firing @m1sh0

Comment: Ensure that all the guard statements have value in it. Write Print statement in else of handleSave() method, also check postBasicInfo is called when the button is tapped

Comment: @Manoj strangely when I try to print the data come in, it has the value. but when in the button there is no value. why is that happening?

Comment: @FerryAdiWijayanto Can you check if the Self (Contrloller/View is not getting deallocated) is not getting deallocated? Looks like your view is getting deallocated

Also can you show me where are you adding print statements?